# Looking for a Midrash about the point that one can learn from everybody

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, commentaries, pirke-avot-ethicsof

I’m looking for (the source of) a Midrash I once heard. It was about a Talmid Chacham who didn’t let himself be lectured by others except for his own Rabbi (or the Rabbi’s). Then he had this encounter with a farmer? or poor/simple man and at the end of the story, the moral of the story teaches us that anyone can learn something from anyone.

It reminded me of Pirkei Avot 4:1 where ben Zoma said something like: Who is wise? He who learns from every man, as it is said: “From all who taught me have I gained understanding” (Psalms 119:99).

Anyone familiar with this midrash/story?
I would love to know where it came from, because I’m sure I’ve read it somewhere before.

Comment: Gemara about Rav Shimon Bar Yochai and the man with 2 hadasim, shomer vzachor?